# Move single byte from memory to xmm register as float

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, simd

How can I retrieve a single byte from an address in memory and move its **value** as a float number into an xmm register? (E.g., if there is a byte 123 at the address location, I want to be able to do floating point arithmetics on this value, 123+5 etc., using sse instructions.)

I am new to assembly, and I hope that the question makes sense. I have tried several things rather randomly (such as moving to `al` first and to xmm from there - but don't know how to proceed to convert to float...); maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to unpack the 8 bit value to 32 bits, then use e.g. [`cvtdq2ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cvtepi32_ps&expand=1478,1407) to convert the 32 bit int to a float.

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/), especially all instructions marked as “Convert.”

Comment: @fuz Thanks for the great link - why couldn't I find this by myself??

Comment: @Duke I dunno.  Work on your Google fu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious scalar way, like you'd get from a compiler (http://godbolt.org/):

```
movzx     eax,  byte [mem]         ; zero extend.  Use movsx to sign-extend
cvtsi2ss  xmm0, eax
```

This costs 3 total uops on Sandybridge-family.  (`cvtsi2ss` is 2).

Note that [`cvtsi2ss`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SS.html) is poorly designed and merges into the old value of XMM0, so it has a false dependency.  gcc tends to `pxor xmm0,xmm0` first to break the dependency, but if XMM0 wasn't recently use then you should be fine.  With AVX, you can zero one XMM register and then repeatedly use it as a safe no-dependency source for multiple converts.

```
vxorps   xmm0, xmm0, xmm0

;then repeated multiple times:
vcvtsi2ss  xmm1, xmm0, eax       ; xmm1 is write-only, no false dep
```

---

If SSE4.1 is available, and it's ok to read 3 bytes past the byte you want (without segfaulting from reading an unmapped page, and without perf problems from cache-line or page splits), then you could do this:

```
pmovzxbd    xmm0,  dword [mem]       ; byte->dword packed zero extend
cvtdq2ps    xmm1,  xmm0              ; packed-convert of int32 to float
```

This costs 2 total uops on SnB-family: `pmovzx/sx` with an XMM destination can micro-fuse a load.  (But not the AVX2 YMM version).  (http://agner.org/optimize/).

Of course this is excellent if you actually *want* to convert 4 consecutive bytes.  Otherwise you might shuffle to set up for a `cvt` instruction if you have multiple conversions.

Comment: Great, it works! Also thanks for the great links - obviously I'm not great at googling...

Comment: @Duke: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more useful links to official docs and performance info.

Comment: Oh yeah, these are a lot of resources! :-) Thanks!